# Problem with TailwindCss on Chrome and Safari

Tags: frontend, tailwind-css

I just finished my first project with **TailwindCSS** the output on FireFox is OK but on the Chrome => blank page & Safari => messed up version.
Any idea about what is happening? I don't get any errors on Terminal and everything seems clear and correct there.

THX

Comment: Not sure we will be able to help you without any specific message. What is the output on firefox? how is the project being run? you have it loaded via cdn or you have it installed via npm?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.